# The requested built-in library is not available on Dartium

Tags: mongodb, dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to make a very simple application that looks up values in a database by using polymer elements to get input.

My main polymer class looks like this:

```dart
library index;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'lookup.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('auth-input')
class AuthInput extends PolymerElement {

  @observable String username = '';
  @observable String password = '';

  AuthInput.created() : super.created();

  void login(Event e, var detail, Node target)
  {
    int code = (e as KeyboardEvent).keyCode;
    switch (code) {
          case 13:
          {
            Database.lookUp(username, password);
            break;
          }
    }
  }

}
```

and a secondary database helper class looks like this:

```dart
library database;

import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

class Database {

  static void lookUp(String username, String password) {

    print("Trying to look up username: " + username + " and password: " + password);
    DbCollection collection;
    Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/main");
    db.open();
    collection = db.collection("auth_data");
    var val = collection.findOne(where.eq("username", username));
    print(val);

    db.close();

  }
}
```

I keep getting this error and I cannot think of a way around it:

```dart
The requested built-in library is not available on Dartium.'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart': error: line 6 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart:io';
```

The strange thing is, I don't want to use `dart:io`. The code works fine either running database processes or running polymer processes. I can't get them to work together. I don't see why this implementation of the code will not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart says

> Server-side driver library for MongoDb implemented in pure Dart.

This means you can't use it in the browser. Your error message indicates the same. The code in the package uses `dart:io` and therefore can't be used in the browser.

Also `mongodb://127.0.0.1/main` is not an URL that can be used from within the browser.

You need a server application that does the DB access and provides an HTTP/WebSocket API to your browser client.

Comment: I got this working using the HTTP/WebSocket API. Dart is somewhat confusing because it's both a client-side and server-side language. I thought they could interface in ways which, now that I think about it, make no sense.

Comment: @Gunter Zochbauer, So if I wanted to use the `googleapis` library to make api calls and update a web site using the `browser` package, how would i do that?  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you please create a new question and provide a bit more concrete information what you try to accomplish. What is the role `googleapis` plays in this scenario? Basically you need a code that runs on a server and this server can access MongoDB using for example the `http_server` package.